Wireguard tunnel to PPTP VPN at OpnSense
I'd like to achieve something like this:

Client connects to Wireguard at OpnSense instance (have that part working)
But the output is not over WAN IP but over PPTP tunnel

The problem is I can't handle configuration - In windows I just put IP+login+password and I'm in. In OpnSense as I understand I need to create Point-To-Point (PPTP) device (Yes I know all about insecure PPTP), but I can't find the correct configuration for fields Local IP address, Remote IP address and the place where I should put Server IP. Is this possible to do?
